# The difference between ElasticsearchTemplate and Resthighlevelclient

Tags: java, elasticsearch, resthighlevelclient

I used to use `ElasticsearchTemplate`to query ES.Recently I found a new component `Resthighlevelclient` can also query ES.Can anyone tell me the difference between the two and how to choose?

Answer (score 2):

1. **ElasticsearchTemplate** is now deprecated and **ElasticSearchRestTemplate** is recommended.

[image]

2. **ElasticSearchRestTemplate** is built on the top of **RestHighLevelClient**. You can think of it as a Spring wrapper over RestHighLevelClient.

[image]

Comment: Thank you.I I'm going to use ElasticSearchRestTemplate now.

Comment: Welcome. Please accept it as an answer it answers your question